# Baire one function and its discontinuity point

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is defined by
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0,\quad x\leq 2,\\
1,\quad x>2.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
The function $f$ above is Baire one function. Recently, I found the definition of Baire one function at a point using $\epsilon-\delta$ notation in Theorem 3.10 and Theorem 3.11 from this [article](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0166864120301139?token=11ACA985A304B9A33E193651C52C193DCC9529D4F81A2FCACC2AD8B15BC38CE26E9B5DC81BCF4C331011BB162BAEA355&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230313051516) , I write it below by using a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

> A function $f$ is Baire one at $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ if for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a positive function $\delta:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that for any $x\in \mathbb{R},$ $$|x-x_0|<\min\{\delta(x),\delta(x_0)\} \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon.$$

Since $f$ is continuous at every point $x_0\neq 2$, then it is true that $f$ is Baire one at every point $x_0\neq 2$.
Now, I am curious, how about if $x_0=2$. Is the function $f$ Baire one at $x_0=2$?
I think $f$ is not Baire one at $x_0=2$.
But I do not know how prove it properly. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should always give a specific reference when asking about the statement of something not particularly well known. In this case, a similar notion appears to have arisen in [Lee/Tang/Zhao 2001](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-08/S0002-9939-00-05826-3/) and has since appeared in a few papers, such as [Fenecios/Cabral 2013](http://www.m-hikari.com/ijma/ijma-2013/ijma-5-8-2013/feneciosIJMA5-8-2013.pdf) and [Balcerzak/Karlova/Szuca](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864121003151). Examination of these papers suggests that you may have misstated something.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for the advice. I have added the link for the reference in my post.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Others will have to investigate this because the paper is behind a paywall and I do not have access, and I do not plan on making a trip to a university library in the near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ characterization of Baire one functions is not a pointwise condition: Fix some $x_0$ and set
$$
\delta(x)=\frac{|x-x_0|}{2} ~ (x \not=x_0), \quad \delta(x_0)=1.
$$
Assume that some $x \not= x_0$ satisfies $|x-x_0|< \min\{\delta(x),\delta(x_0)\}= \min\{|x-x_0|/2,1\}$.

1. If $|x-x_0| < 2$, then $|x-x_0| < |x-x_0|/2$, a contradiction.
2. If $|x-x_0| \ge 2$, then $|x-x_0| < 1 < 2 \le |x-x_0|$, a contradiction.

Thus $|x-x_0|< \min\{\delta(x),\delta(x_0)\}$ implies $x=x_0$. Then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|= 0 <\varepsilon$. So each function $f$ has this property at each point $x_0$.

The $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ characterization of Baire one functions reads (see the first link from the comment of Dave L. Renfro):

For any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a function $\delta:\mathbb{R} \to (0,\infty)$ such that
$$
\forall x,y: ~~ |x-y|< \min\{\delta(x),\delta(y)\} \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| <\varepsilon
$$

Comment: why do you consider $|x-x_0|<2$ and $|x-x_0|\geq 2$?

Comment: @user136524 Since $\min\{|x-x_0|/2,1\} = |x-x_0|/2$ if $|x-x_0|< 2$, and $\min\{|x-x_0|/2,1\} = 1$ if $|x-x_0| \ge 2$.